# Resolve promises sequentially and break the sequence if one of the promises in the sequence throws an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have three `async` functions set as below:

```
const stepOne = async () => { setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("step 1")
}, 3000)  }

const stepTwo = async () => { throw new Error("Error at step two") }

const stepThree = async () => { console.log("step 3") }
```

How will I execute all these functions sequentially and break the promise chain at stepTwo not allowing stepThree function to run ever?

So,

normal sequence is like this: stepOne --> stepTwo --> stepThree

sequence with error thrown at stepTwo: stepOne --> stepTwo

The error thrown at stepTwo needs to get caught at end catch block.

UPDATE #1: Missed a crucial element of the question. await cannot be used as these three functions need to be called within a function which is not async.

example:

```
const testFunc = () => { 
  
  resolve three promises 
  sequentially, break the promise chain when error is thrown 
  and ultimately, catch errors here
   
  }
```

Comment: Generally: `try { await stepOne(); await stepTwo(); await stepThree(): } catch ...`. However, your `stepOne` doesn't wait for the `setTimeout` to resolve. There's no way to await that `setTimeout` without changing the implementation of `stepOne`…

Comment: @deceze : My apologies! await is not an option. updated my question.

Comment: If you can't use `await`, then you cannot catch the error by `try..catch`. You need to chain them with the good old `then.then.catch`.

Comment: @deceze : yes, understand. however, I wanted to notify that error need to be caught. Shouldn't have used try.. catch block if it was misleading. I removed it from the question.

Comment: So: `stepOne().then(stepTwo).then(stepThree).catch(e => console.error(e))`…

Answer (score 2):

Your code would work if you would resolve the promise from `stepOne` because `setTimeout` just adds the function to the stack and is not waiting for it to resolve.

If you would return a Promise from `stepOne` and resolve it after the `console.log` then the `try catch` will wait for `stepOne` and catch the error on `stepTwo`

Here is your code example

```
const stepOne = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("step 1")
            resolve(true);
        }, 3000)
    });
}

const stepTwo = async () => { throw new Error("Error at step two") }

const stepThree = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("step 3")
            resolve(true);
        }, 3000)
    });
}


(() => {
    stepOne()
        .then(stepTwo)
        .then(stepThree)
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })  
})();
```

Now the `console.log` looks like this

```
step 1
Error: Error at step two
    at stepTwo (/home/user/develop/test/stackoverflow.js:10:38)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Comment: My apologies! await is not an option. updated my question.

Comment: If you not fine with the given answers from the `This question already has answers here:` flag i updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code. You need to wait for each call (stepOne, stepTwo and stepThree) so that when there is any exception, the next call is not made.

```
try {
    await stepOne();
    await stepTwo();
    await stepThree()
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: My apologies! await is not an option. updated my question.

Comment: You have 2 options if the main function is not async. You can wrap my sample code in IIFE or go for .then .then .catch

Comment: ( async ()=>  {// above code sample })(); should work

Answer (score 1):

If your steps are functions that return a Promise, you could create a wrapper function that will call each step in sequence and abort if a step fails, logging details of which step failed.

In this example, each step fails with a 1 in 5 chance.

```js
// Make a step proc, that throws 1 time in 5
function createStep(index) {
    let error = (Math.random() < 0.2) ? new Error(`Step ${index+1} error`) : null ;
    return () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(error ? reject(error): resolve(`Step ${index+1} outcome`), 500));
}

async function runSteps(steps) {
   
   for(stepIndex = 0; stepIndex < steps.length; stepIndex++) {
       try {
         console.log(`Running step #${stepIndex+1}...`);
         let result = await steps[stepIndex]();
         console.log(`Step result:`, result);
       } catch (e) { 
         console.error(`An error occurred at step #${stepIndex+1}:`, e.message);
         break;
       }
       if (stepIndex === (steps.length -1) ) {
          console.log("All steps completed successfully");
       }
   }
}

let steps = Array.from( { length: 3 }, (v,k) => createStep(k));
runSteps(steps);
```

Comment: My apologies! await is not an option. updated my question.